# Ambiguity in Ampere's law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In Ampere's law the positive direction of the current is pointed by the thumb while curling the right hand in the direction assigned to the Ampèrean loop. But what if this method gives different directions at different parts of the loop ? For example this awful loop drawn by me:-
[image]

Comment: You will need to add up the contribution from each individual line segment. The field $d\vec B$ sourced by a given infinitesimal line segment $d\vec \ell$ with be in the direction given by the right hand rule. The total field comes from integrating over the entire curve.

Comment: @hft that should be an answer

Comment: @hft .Please elaborate.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you mean by "amperean loop." Do you mean a loop along which the field is constant? Do you mean any closed loop in space over which you can integrate the field? I assume it is either one of these two options in my updated answer, but I'm not sure...

Comment: You just rediscovered why calculus was invented – in order to take an arbitrary complicated shape and reduce it into pieces where every relationship is either linear or constant.

Answer (score 5):

> But what if this method gives different directions at different parts of the loop?

---

**Update:**

As pointed out by OP in the comments, OP is interested in an Amperean loop, whereas my original answer addressed a physical wire loop.

For an Amperean loop, as opposed to a physical loop of wire, the method can not give different directions at different points on the loop. This is because by definition an Amperean loop describes an arbitrary closed-loop path through a field that is already known. That is, any closed-loop path over which you integrate $\vec B(\vec r, t) \cdot d\vec\ell$, where $\vec B(\vec r, t)$ is a known function of space and time (or just space in magnetostatics).

It usually goes without saying, but a magnetic field is a "field" in the usual physics sense; it is simply a vector-valued *function* of space and time. Since it is a *function* it can only have a single value at a given point in space and time (otherwise it would not be a function).

So, given that $\vec B(\vec r, t)$ is already specified completely, and assuming the path of the Amperean loop is parametrized as $\vec q(s)$ with $\vec q(0)=\vec q(1)$, the loop integral can be written as
$$
\int_0^1 ds \frac{d\vec q(s)}{ds}\cdot\vec B(\vec q(s),t)\;.
$$

Because the above paragraphs seem like a fairly trivial answer, or an answer *by definition* alone, I will retain my original answer below, since it may help elucidate how lots of individual contributions to the magnetic field can be summed up at a fixed point in space and result in the total field at that point in space.

---

Individual parts of a physical wire loop can indeed produce fields with different directions, in general. You need to add up all the contributions from all the individual line segments to get the total field at any given point.

The contribution to the field $d\vec B$ from an individual infinitesimal line segment $d\vec \ell$ is:
$$
d\vec B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}I\frac{d\vec \ell\times (\vec r - \vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|^3}\;.
$$
where $\vec r$ is the location where the field is being evaluated and $\vec r'$ is the location of the segment of wire $d\vec \ell$.

The total field at any given point $\vec r$ is:
$$
\vec B(\vec r)=\int d\vec B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}I\int\frac{d\vec \ell\times (\vec r - \vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|^3}\;,\tag{1}
$$
which tends to be a difficult integral to evaluate in general, but has well known evaluations in special cases such as an infinite straight wire.

---

To make Eq. (1) a little more concrete, suppose that you have written down a parameterization of your curved wire loop as:
$$
\vec r' = \vec q(s)\;,
$$
where $s$ is a single real number that can be chosen to run, say, from 0 to 1, for a finite segment of wire, or, say, from negative infinity to infinity for an infinite segment of wire.

Then Eq. (1) can be re-written in terms of an integration over a single real number $s$ as:
$$
\vec B(\vec r)=  \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}I\int_0^1 ds\frac{d\vec q(s)}{ds}\times \frac{(\vec r - \vec q(s))}{|\vec r - \vec q(s)|^3}\;,\tag{2}
$$

For example, evaluating the above Eq. (2) for an infinite straight wire results in:
$$
\vec B(\vec r)=  \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi R}I\hat\theta\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{(3/2)}}
= \frac{\mu_0}{2\pi R}I\hat\theta
\;,
$$
where $R$ is the radial distance from the wire and $\hat \theta$ is the azimuthal direction.

Comment: Excellent answer +1. IMO, your comment itself was a decent answer already, and this is much better

Comment: Thanks, @Dale! :)

Comment: @hft.The loop drawn above is not a current loop.It's an ampèrean loop.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar Yes, you are right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Start at any point on your awesome 'folded' path and observe whether, in a complete tracing of the path returning to your starting point, you have gone round the current-carrying wire in a clockwise or anticlockwise manner. Apply the right hand rule accordingly to a simplified clockwise or anticlockwise path.

I tried it using my Mac's on-screen chiroform 'pointer' at various places on your diagram, to represent the current-carrying wire. With the pointer in some places, the path didn't actually go round the pointer (even though this wasn't obvious from a quick glance) so the integral $\mathbf B.d\mathbf s$ around the loop would be zero.

Comment: But it seems that starting from different parts leads to different sense(i.e,clockwise or anticlockwise).

Comment: I don't see how. Provided that you bear in mind the position of the current-carrying wire as you go once round the loop, it doesn't matter where on the loop you start. You always get the same sense of rotation about the current-carrying wire. You certainly do with the loop you've drawn so nicely: if we regard the loop as a creature and, starting with the foot, we shade inside it, right the way up to its curly neck and head, then if we go round the loop in the sense of the arrows we go clockwise round any current-carrying wire that passes through the page in the shaded area.

Comment: After trying very hard to understand your point I am still not able to understand and very confused.Would you please elaborate a little more with an example (e.g, a current wire passing through the curved part)?

Comment: I'm sorry to have confused you. Did you follow what I meant about shading the area inside the loop? And the idea of having the current-carrying wire passing through the shaded area? If so, we're ready to go... Start at any point on your loop and trace round it once in the sense of your arrows. You will find that you've gone once round the wire in a clockwise sense.